# PHP - Search array in array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have tried googling for the past one hour straight now and tried many ways to search for an array, in an array.

My objective is, to find a keyword in the URL,  and the keywords are in a txt file.

This is what i have so far - but doesn't work.

```
$file = "keywords.txt";
$open = fopen($file,'r');
$data = fread($open,filesize($file));
$data = explode(" ",$data);
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = parse_url($url); //parse the URL into an array

foreach($data as $d)
{
    if(strstr($d,$url))
    {
    echo "yes";
    }
}
```

This works WITHOUT the text file, or array - but that's not what i want.

I'd appreciate it if anyone can assist me.

Comment: Were you able to get it working Anonymous2011?

Comment: what do you mean when you say its not working.what are u expecting and what is it giving?

Comment: I tried using in_array() like vap0r's method below, but that didn't work for some reason, although i'm sure that's what i did before...

What i meant by it not working, was the expected outcome was php to echo "yes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
$file = "keywords.txt";
$open = fopen($file,'r');
$data = fread($open,filesize($file));
$data = explode(" ",$data);
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = parse_url($url); //parse the URL into an array
foreach($data as $d){
  if(in_array($d,$url)){
    echo "yes";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vap0r, it worked perfectly -  I'm more than sure i tried that method before (in_array()) lol.